# el.scrollTop for an element leaves some space at the top of the screen?

Tags: javascript

- I have a simple `conversation-body` class with `overflow: auto` property.
- I need this div to scroll to top by the amount of its height.

Here is what I have done so far -:

```
//getting element 
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('conversation-body')[0]; 
//getting height
var parentHeight = parent.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - parent.getBoundingClientRect().top;
//trying to scroll it up
parent.scrollTop += parentHeight;
```

- This works but it leave some space on the top.
- Any suggestion why ?
- [Here](https://response-designer-dev.netlify.com/) is the link to webpage. You can try above code in the
  console.

[image]

Comment: can you clear the browser cache and check. also disable any caching plug-in if it exist in you app

Comment: Tried that in incognito, getting same issue. Edit: same issue in ff and chrome

Answer (score 0):

To confirm, you want to display the next section of the page by the height of the parent?

If so, try using [`offsetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight) instead of calculating it from the rectangle coordinates.

```js
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('conversation-body')[0]; //getting element
parent.scrollTop += parent.offsetHeight; // no need to perform height calculation
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is how you get the parent height. I'm not familiar with `getBoundingClientRect`, I use `offsetHeight`. I tried it like that and it worked:

```
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('conversation-body')[0]; //getting element
var parentHeight = parent.offsetHeight; //getting height
parent.scrollTop += parentHeight; //trying to scroll it up
```